# Can't create patch for file with size more than 500Kb

Tags: intellij-idea, perforce, patch

I'm using an *IntelliJ IDEA* IDE with *Perforce* as a VCS.

I have a changelist with a file which size is about 1.5 Mb. When I'm trying to create patch file IDEA just excludes it from file list and shows an error next to filename:

```
File size is bigger than 500K
```

How can I avoid this restriction?

Comment: The limit is hardcoded, there is an issue logged about it: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-95669 .